# Minecraft command blocks and gamerules

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I get a command block make `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true`
but at the same time make sure this said command block doesn't say that it updated the gamerule?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. Why would you want to do that anyways?

Comment: Couldn't you just execute `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true` yourself, then run the command blocks?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as I'm aware, but I'll look into it. There are multiple gamerules to hide command output, but sadly only commandBlockOutput affects (you guessed it) the command block output.

Also, commandBlockOutput is generally set to false to prevent command output spam, say from a 20t/s clock. I could only imagine that you're trying to be extremely secretive on someone else's server, or just trying to be a jerk to all operators (As only operators can see the output).

But reading the question over, are you talking about the output bar in the command block, or the chat output? If it's the output bar, then it's possible. If it's chat, then it's impossible.